# Trouble with Audit-Logout Event Handler

Tags: sql-server, event-handling, message-queue, database-cursor

I need to be able to 'catch' ending of SQL Server Sessions so I can run a routine on any database that session has used.  I have found a few samples of Queue Notifications and that is what I am currently trying to use.

In the code below, it works as-is.   But when I remove the comments on the cursor Open inside of the 'activated' stored procedure, the @@ROWCOUNT returns 0 and the queue is then deactivated.   Further messages just continue to build up.   Doing a `RECEIVE TOP(1) * FROM dbo.queNotification` gives error:

```
Msg 9617, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dbo.ReceiveEvent, Line 12 [Batch Start Line 177]
The service queue "queNotification" is currently disabled.
```

I try running the routine manually after enabling the queue again...  It runs fine.  It just does not want to run under the broker setup.

```
create table ##ENLog (
       [msg] varchar(max),
       [when] datetime2 NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_LogoutAudit__time_acquired DEFAULT sysdatetime()
       )

CREATE DATABASE ENTesting;
GO
ALTER DATABASE ENTesting   SET ENABLE_BROKER;
GO
USE ENTesting;

CREATE QUEUE queNotification;
CREATE SERVICE svcNotification ON QUEUE queNotification ([http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostEventNotification]);
CREATE EVENT NOTIFICATION enEvents ON SERVER FOR AUDIT_LOGOUT TO SERVICE 'svcNotification', 'current database';
GO

ALTER QUEUE dbo.queNotification WITH ACTIVATION (PROCEDURE_NAME = dbo.ReceiveEvent, STATUS = OFF);
ALTER QUEUE dbo.queNotification WITH STATUS = OFF;
GO

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ReceiveEvent AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @MsgBody XML

    WHILE (1 = 1)
    BEGIN
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
        insert into ##ENLog (msg) values ('START');

        WAITFOR (                                       -- Receive the next available message from the queue
            RECEIVE TOP(1)                              -- just handle one message at a time
            @MsgBody = CAST(message_body AS XML)
            FROM queNotification), TIMEOUT 1000         -- if the queue is empty for one second, relax
        IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)                             -- If we didn't get anything, bail out
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;                       -- this will undo the RECEIVE
            insert into ##ENLog (msg) values ('NO MORE ROWS');
            BREAK;
        END ELSE BEGIN
            BEGIN TRAN
            insert into ##ENLog (msg) values ('GOT ROW');
            declare @spid       smallint     = @MsgBody.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SPID)[1]',           'smallint')
            declare @dbid       int          = @MsgBody.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseID)[1]',     'int')
            declare @host_name  sysname      = @MsgBody.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/HostName)[1]',       'sysname')
            declare @login_name sysname      = @MsgBody.value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)[1]',      'sysname')

            declare @msg nvarchar(max) =  'spid ' + convert(nvarchar, @spid) + char(10) + char(9) + 'dbid ' + convert(nvarchar, @dbid) + char(10) + char(9) + 'host ' + @host_name   + char(10) + char(9) + 'login ' + @login_name + char(10) + char(9);
            insert into ##ENLog (msg) values (@msg);

            declare @cur cursor
            declare @dbname sysname
            begin
                insert into ##ENLog (msg) values ('Start Cursor');
                SET @cur = CURSOR FOR
                    select name from sys.databases d
                        where database_id>4 and object_id([name] + '.mds.DeinitSession') IS NOT NULL
                BEGIN TRY
                    print '' -- nop
----    uncomment anything below here and it stops working
----                    OPEN @cur
----                    insert into ##ENLog (msg) values ('Cursor Opened');
----                    FETCH NEXT FROM @cur INTO @dbname
----                    insert into ##ENLog (msg) values ('Fetch Called');
----                    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 begin
----                        insert into ##ENLog (msg) values ('Calling Deinit on ' + @dbname);
----
----                        declare @sql nvarchar(256) = 'USE btrtest' + char(10) + 'insert into ##ENLog (msg) values (''deinit ' + @dbname + ''')'
----                        insert into ##ENLog (msg) values (@sql);
----                        execute(@sql)
----                        FETCH NEXT FROM @cur INTO @dbname
----                    end
----                    insert into ##ENLog (msg) values ('Close Cursor');
----                    CLOSE @cur
----                    DEALLOCATE @cur
                END TRY BEGIN CATCH
                    set @msg = N'Exception Error: ' + N' Msg ' + convert(nvarchar, ERROR_NUMBER()) + N', Level ' + convert(nvarchar, ERROR_SEVERITY()) + N', Stat '  + convert(nvarchar, ERROR_STATE()) + N', Line ' + convert(nvarchar, ERROR_LINE()) + N', Proc ' + isnull(ERROR_PROCEDURE(),'--') + N'  ' + ERROR_MESSAGE();
                    insert into ##ENLog (msg) values (@msg);
                END CATCH
            end

            insert into ##ENLog (msg) values ('Commit');
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
       
            -- Commit the transaction.  At any point before this, we could roll back - the received message would be back on the queue AND the response wouldn't be sent.
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
        END
    END
GO


ALTER QUEUE dbo.queNotification
    WITH ACTIVATION ( PROCEDURE_NAME = dbo.ReceiveEvent, STATUS = ON, MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 1, EXECUTE AS OWNER)
GO
ALTER QUEUE dbo.queNotification WITH STATUS = ON;
GO



SELECT * FROM dbo.queNotification;

select * from ##ENLog
```

Answer (score 0):

Service broker has a poison message detection/mitigation mechanism whereby if a rollback happens (iirc) five times in a row, it shuts the whole thing down. One thing that is weird to me is this:

```
IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)                             -- If we didn't get anything, bail out
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;                       -- this will undo the RECEIVE
            insert into ##ENLog (msg) values ('NO MORE ROWS');
            BREAK;
        END
```

If you didn't get any rows end the procedure, don't roll back.

Comment: Very good to know this.    Thanks Ben.

The RollBack came from the sample code I took this from.   I will remove it.